Speakers Not recognised in linux
So I own a Lenovo ThinkPad e-14 and it got damaged and restored recently in windows the speakers seem to work fine but they didn't switch inputs automatically and I had to switch them manually from settings and when I installed Linux the speakers stopped working completely and wasn't even recognised by my laptop I'm new to linux and this is a big issue so any help?
